# Getting a full list of companies registered in Malta

Tags: business

The Malta business registry provides a calendar option to download data on companies on 15 days chunks http://rocsupport.mfsa.com.mt/pages/RecentlyRegisteredCompanies.aspx

I am pretty sure the calendar tool can be tricked and an argument can be passed so that an entire list of all companies registered can be retrieved at once. I've tried several options with no luck.

Has somebody done it or has similar experience?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it programatically in R using a combination of [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) and [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) packages to navigate then screen scrape your data. Then you can iteratively go through each 15 day chunk going back in time.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I thought about it. However I am still hoping that we can pass the request in such a way that it will save me from that trouble.

Comment: @marfi, Unfortunately, I can't see how to inject a parameter into the URL and my understanding of the page source isnt good enough.